# Can't change any settings

Tags: unity

When I open my session, the wallpaper changed to the default one and I can't change any settings. When it happened for the first time I was running on Ubuntu 13.10, I have upgraded to 14.04 LTS hoping that it would fix the problem, but unfortunately it didn't.

Comment: Where is your desktop wallpaper located? What do you mean you can't change any settings?

Answer (score 6):

I fixed the problem by deleting the `.cache` `.compiz` and `.config` folders from my home folder.

Comment: Just to confirm that this works. I had the same issue (not being able to change any user settings and few other annoyances). I spent almost entire day trying various things with no success. Deleting .config and .cache folders magically repairs everything. Thank you man..

Comment: I love you so much!

Answer (score 0):

When I encountered this issue it turned out I mistakenly changed the ownership of the "user" file in `/home/{my user}/.config/dconf/`. Changing the ownership of `/home/{my user}/.config/dconf/user` back to `{myuser}:{my user}` fixed the issue, e. g.:

```
sudo chown dennis:dennis /home/dennis/.config/dconf/user
```

I figured out where the issue was by tailing `/home/{my user}/.cache/upstart/unity-settings-daemon.log` while trying to change settings.

```
(unity-settings-daemon:2157): dconf-WARNING **: failed to commit changes to dconf: GDBus.Error:org.gtk.GDBus.UnmappedGError.Quark._g_2dfile_2derror_2dquark.Code2: Cannot open dconf database: Failed to open file '/home/dennis/.config/dconf/user': Permission denied
```